# Move Python Folder Into Program Files Folder?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.3, program-files

I have Python27 and Python33 folders. Can I move these folders into my Program Files folder or will this cause problems?[image]

Comment: A better question might be, is the risk of mangling something important and not being able to get things working right again worth whatever benefit having those folders in Program Files might give? Why do you need those folders in Program Files?

Comment: Because I don't want clutter in my C drive, I want all my programs located in my Program Files folder!

Comment: Some installation programs and utilities have problems with embedded spaces in directory names in the path.  You could argue that they should handle it, but the fact is that some do not.  Best to avoid problems rather than invite them and use the default names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply moving folders will not work.

- Python file association will not work.
- `.pyc` file contains absolute path:

  - You will get old paths in tracebacks.
- Third-party libraries may have absolute path.

You need to reinstall the interpreter and libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not if you update your path variable to reflect the changes